# Exclude specific product tags from related products in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I use the following command line to exclude specific tags products from related WooCommerce products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_tag_terms', 'remove_related_tags' );
function remove_related_tags( $terms ) {
  foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
    if ( 'Đồng Hồ Thụy Sỹ' === $term->name ) {
      unset( $terms[ $key ] );
    }
    if ( 'dong-ho-thuy-sy' === $term->slug ) {
      unset( $terms[ $key ] );
    }
    if ( 'Đồng Hồ 6 Kim' === $term->name ) {
      unset( $terms[ $key ] );
    }
    if ( 'Citizen Eco-Drive' === $term->name ) {
      unset( $terms[ $key ] );
    }
    if ( 'Seiko Kinetic' === $term->name ) {
      unset( $terms[ $key ] );
    }
    if ( 'Seiko Solar' === $term->name ) {
      unset( $terms[ $key ] );
    }
    if ( 'Đồng Hồ Dây Da Nam Nữ' === $term->name ) {
      unset( $terms[ $key ] );
    }
  }
  return $terms;
}
```

But since WooCommerce update version 3 this code doesn't work anymore and has no effect.

Is there any other way I can exclude specific tags products from related products?

Answer (score 0):

Since woocommerce 3, things have change everywhere. Now in that hook there is not anymore an array of the product tag terms objects, but only an array of the terms IDs… That's why your code is not working.

It should work replacing it with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_tag_terms', 'remove_related_tags', 10, 2 );
function remove_related_tags( $tag_terms_ids, $product_id  ){

    // Get the product tag term object by field type and converting it to term ID
    function get_term_id_by( $value, $type, $tax = 'product_tag' ){
        return get_term_by( $type, $value, $tax )->term_id;
    }
    // Set here the product tag term by field type to exclude
    $exclude_terms_ids = array(
        get_term_id_by( 'Đồng Hồ Thụy Sỹ', 'name' ),
        get_term_id_by( 'dong-ho-thuy-sy', 'slug' ),
        get_term_id_by( 'Đồng Hồ 6 Kim', 'name' ),
        get_term_id_by( 'Citizen Eco-Drive', 'name' ),
        get_term_id_by( 'Seiko Kinetic', 'name' ),
        get_term_id_by( 'Seiko Solar', 'name' ),
        get_term_id_by( 'Đồng Hồ Dây Da Nam Nữ', 'name' ),
    );

    // Removing the necessary product tag terms IDs from the array
    foreach ( $tag_terms_ids as $key => $term_id )
        foreach ( $exclude_terms_ids as $exclude_term_id )
            if ( $term_id == $exclude_term_id )
                unset( $tag_terms_ids[ $key ] );

    // Return the custom array of product tag terms IDs
    return $tag_terms_ids;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> But Unfortunately it will not work as it seems that there is a bug related to `woocommerce_get_related_product_tag_terms` and `woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms` since WooCommerce 3

Comment: Hello Loic TheAztec, thank you for your support. I tried but it did not seem to work. No effect whatsoever. Do you think of any other way?

Comment: Hello @ĐặngHảiTriều I have make some further test, and it seems that there is a bug for that hooks. So It's ot possible to get them work.